# Create custom folder based on user input(folder choice dialog) using Advanced Installer 12.4.2

Tags: c#, directory, advanced-installer

My application needs to use some files(both read and write operation included) which must be located in particular folders. If I place those folders in my applications root directory, I get run time errors as unless the user is an administrator, he/she can not write in  "c:\blah\blah..." But I don't know how to create folder by prompting the user to provide a location other than "c:\ " How can this be done while using advanced installer Enterprise type project. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say how to do that with installer, but you can use AppData folder to store your application files.

Comment: Thanks Ruben, for replying.. my question is will it prevent the run time error( a message showing... Can not use "c:\...\..", access to this file is denied).

Comment: You can prompt user to select location when you are saving file using `SaveFileDialog` and check do you have permission to save file in thtat folder using `FileIOPermission` class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission(v=vs.110).aspx